# Can't resolve all parameters for extends component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a simple `BaseComponent` in `angular 6` that has `one` parameter.
the other of components Inherite from `BaseComponent`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'base-component',
    template: ``
})
export class BaseComponent
{
    constructor(private type: number)
    {
        console.log("type value is " , type);
    }
}
```

and `HomeComponent` is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnDestroy 
{
    constructor() 
    {
        super(1); //simple number
    }
    ngOnDestroy() { }
}
```

it's compiled with `ng b --watch` but when I exec `ng b --prod`, I encountered with this error:

> ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for BaseComponent in
>   E:/app/src/app/win-forms/base.component.ts: (?).

when I remove the `type` parameter from `constructor` , it's `build` well.

how to use the `constractor` with simple the `parameter`?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark `BaseComponent` as abstract so it cant be instantiated directly as well as remove the `@Component` attribute.

```
// ← removed @Component attribute
export abstract class BaseComponent {
  /* unchanged code removed for brevity */
}
```

The reason for the error is that currently you *could* use the selector `base-component` somewhere and the angular framework would have no idea what to inject into the constructor as the type `number` has not been registered with the DI framework.

If you must be able to create an instance of it directly and you have a static value somewhere that needs to be passed to it then you need to register this with the angular using `InjectionToken`.

Example:

```
/* I have omitted a lot of "standard" code for brevity that is not of interest for the purpose of this example */

import { InjectionToken, Inject } from '@angular/core';


export const YOUR_STATIC_VALUE_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<number>('SomeNumber');

export function someNumberFactory(): any {
    return 18; // return the value you want to hard code
}

@NgModule({
    providers: [{ provide: YOUR_STATIC_VALUE_TOKEN, useFactory: someNumberFactory}]
})
export class YourModule { }

export abstract class BaseComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(YOUR_STATIC_VALUE_TOKEN) private type: number) {}
}
```

Comment: thanks @Igor, but when I Use the `abstract`, the project encounterd with this error: `Type 'typeof BaseComponent' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.
  Type 'typeof BaseComponent' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'.
    Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.ts`